# how to open default page in browser from Apache web server..?

Tags: java, apache, apache2, webserver

I have started Apache Web server and put all the required configuration in httpd.conf file like

```
 DocumentRoot "c:/Apache2/htdocs"
 <Directory "c:/Apache2/htdocs">
 <Directory> DirectoryIndex
```

when i'm opening localhost in browser that time it not opening index.html document which is stored in htdocs directory. can someone please suggest my what i'm missing here, Thanks in Advance .

Answer (score 0):

At the end you have to write the name of file 'index.html'

```
 DocumentRoot "c:/Apache2/htdocs"
 <Directory "c:/Apache2/htdocs">
 <Directory> DirectoryIndex index.html
```